# PHP won't insert data to Mysql database - No error thrown

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

Hi so I can't seem to find any help on this topic because there is no error being thrown. I am trying to insert records to a database via php using mysqli_query but after the re-direct no changes are made. I have three files I am working with, index.php, conn.php and new.php. index.php and new.php are located in the same folder but conn.php is one directory below.
index.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khula" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <script>
        $(function()
        {
            $('.error').fadeOut(10000);
        });
    </script>

    <body>

        <header>
           <img src="images/logo.png"> 
            <p>The reliable bus company</p>
        </header>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="titletxt">
                    <h4>Drivers</h4>

                </div>
                <?php
        include '../conn.php';
        mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee");

        echo "
        <div class='table_content'>
        <table align='center'>
        <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
        <th>Job Position</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        </tr>
        ";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['employeeID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['contactNum'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['DOB'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table></div>";


        ?>


                <!-- Record Insert -->
                <br>
                <div class="titletxt">
                    <h4>Insert a Record</h4>
                </div>
                <h3 style="font-weight: 400; margin-left: 5px;">New Employee</h3>
                <form class="insert_form" action="new.php" method="post" name="insert_form">
                    <label>Title: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" required><br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $titleErr ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" required> <br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <label>Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address" required><br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $addressErr ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <label>Contact Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contactNum" required><br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $contactErr ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <label>Job Position</label>
                    <input type="text" name="position" required><br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $positionErr ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <label>Gender: </label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required> Male
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required> Female<br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <label>DOB: </label>
                    <input style="width: 60px;" type="text" name="DOB_year" required>YYYY
                    <input style="width: 30px;" type="text" name="DOB_months" required>MM
                    <input type="text" name="DOB_day" style="width: 30px" required>DD<br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $DOBErr ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" Value="Insert Entry">

                </form>


            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

conn.php:

```
    <?php 
   $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "bus_db";
    global $conn;
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Mysql Error has occured" . mysqli_connect_error;
    }

    else if(!mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "<connection>Connection Established</connection>";
    }


function close_connection()
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_close($conn);
}

$title = $name = $address = $contact = $position = $gender = $DOB = "";
                      $titleErr = $nameErr = $addressErr = $contactErr = $positionErr = $genderErr = $DOBErr = ""; 
                mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
                    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
                      {
                          if (empty($_POST["title"]))
                          {
                              $titleErr = "Title is Required";
                          }else{
                              $title = input($_POST["title"]);
                          }

                          if (empty($_POST["name"]))
                          {
                              $nameErr = "Name is Required";
                          }else
                          {
                              $name = input($_POST["name"]);
                              if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                                    $nameErr = "Invalid Name"; 
                            }
                          }

                          if (empty($_POST["address"]))
                          {
                              $addressErr = "Address is Required";
                          }else{
                              $address = input($_POST["address"]);
                          }

                            if (empty($_POST["contactNum"]))
                            {
                                $contactErr = "Contact Number is required ";
                            }else{
                                $contact = input($_POST["contactNum"]);
                                $regex = "^([0-9]{10,11})$^";
                                if (!preg_match($regex, $contact)) {
                                    $contactErr = "Invalid Phone Number";
                                }
                            }

                            if(empty($_POST["position"]))
                            {
                                $positionErr = "Position is required";
                            }else{
                                $position = input($_POST["position"]);
                            }

                            if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
                            {
                                $genderErr = "Gender is Required";
                            }else{
                                $gender = input($_POST["gender"]);
                            }

                            if (empty($_POST["DOB_year"]) || empty($_POST["DOB_months"]) || empty($_POST["DOB_day"]))
                            {
                                $DOBErr = "Invalid entry for date of birth";
                            }else
                            {
                                $DOB = input($_POST["DOB_year"] + "/" + $_POST["DOB_months"] + "/" + $_POST["DOB_day"]);
                            }
                      }
                      function input($data) {
                          $data = trim($data);
                          $data = stripslashes($data);
                          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                          return $data;
                      }

function insert_records($p_title, $p_name, $p_address, $p_contact, $p_position, $p_gender, $p_DOB)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_employee VALUES(null, '" .$p_title."', '".$p_name."', '".$p_address."', '".$p_contact."', '".$p_position."', '".$p_gender."', '".$p_DOB."')");
}
?>
```

new.php:

```
<?php 
include '../conn.php';
insert_records($title, $name, $address, $contact, $position, $gender, $DOB);
header( 'Location:index.php');
close_connection();
?>
```

I would appreciate any, thanks

Comment: *"No error thrown"* - I didn't see `mysqli_error($conn)` or any error reporting done.

Comment: `$DOB = input($_POST["DOB_year"] + "/" + $_POST["DOB_months"] + "/" + $_POST["DOB_day"]);` are you doing math? I doubt it.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit your `insert_records()` to give you feedback if `mysqli_query` fails.

```
function insert_records($p_title, $p_name, $p_address, $p_contact, $p_position, $p_gender, $p_DOB)
{
    global $conn;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'some query') or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    return $result;
}
```

and read about how you can prevent MySQL injection here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

---

edit:

> $DOB = input($_POST["DOB_year"] + "/" + $_POST["DOB_months"] + "/" + $_POST["DOB_day"]);

in php '+' is used to do calculations. if you want to concatenate strings use '.'

```
$DOB = input($_POST["DOB_year"] . "/" . $_POST["DOB_months"] . "/" . $_POST["DOB_day"]);
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for your to help. The page now shows me the error: Incorrect date value: ' ' for column 'DOB' at row 1. Any idea what data format needs to be entered into the form for it to be accepted by the database

Comment: After a bit more research I found a post saying that php inserts for sql should be written like this: ,
CAST('". $date ."' AS DATE))"). So i changed my code to , CAST('". $p_DOB ."' AS DATE))") or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); and the error I get now is Query failed: Incorrect datetime value: '' Any suggestions?